# can't find where to add "OAuth redirect URL" in meta for developers

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I'm trying to add "login with facebook" feature to my website. I made the app setup in "meta for developers" but I can't find where to add "**OAuth redirect URL**". All the old tutorials was made before the update of the website and they say go to "add product section" but I don't had a product section in the left side bar. I spent a lot of time to search for it but ... :(

here is a screenshot the app page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqHqN.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the exact same problem from following outdated tutorials just like you.

## Here is how I did it:

Select your application from the dropdown.

Under build your app, click "use cases".

Where it says "Authentication and Account Creation", click "Customize".

Click "Go to Settings".

There will be a "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" field (Until things change again), which I believe is what you are after.

I hope this helps.

[Customize page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUvyq.png)

Comment: The first time I had to integrate Facebook API into a website was 10 years ago. And the biggest problem was poor and unclear documentation. Looks like nothing has changed since then. :)